# How can I load an image in Pygame through a text file

Tags: python, pygame

This is a small section of my pygame code.
I am trying to get a random Image to be loaded.
In the text file I have 10 different paths to different images.

```
random_number = random.randint(0,9)
file = open('ImagePath.txt','r')
paths = file.readlines()
path = paths[random_number]
Img = pygame.image.load(path)
Display.blit(Img, (20,20))
```

When I run the code it says the image cannot be accessed and that the error is found on the line:

`Img = pygame.image.load(path)`

Comment: Probably, you are using relative paths and they are probably not relative to your script. We can only guess if you don't provide more info. For example what does `print(path)` give.

Comment: @zxckv there are many problems, check my answer below to ensure your providing `pygame.image.load()` the correct relative image path.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is unclear what is being asked about and there is no [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).